# Facing issue when calling Oracle BIP report rest apis

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, bi-publisher, oracle-fusion-apps, oracle-rest-data-services

When trying to trigger the oracle bip report api i'm facing 404 issue. Can anyone guide me if doing something wrong

url -> https://example.oraclepdemos.com:432/xmlpserver/services/rest/v1/reports/Custom/ISW/ISW_OCA_Data_Access_Report/run?P_Sec_Attr=Hello&P_File_Identifier=11022323171717

type : post

Authorization -> basic (passing correct username and password)

Headers :-

Content-Type -> multipart/form-data;boundary="Boundary_1_1153447573_1465550731355"
Accept -> multipart/form-data

Body:-

--Boundary_1_1153447573_1465550731355
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ReportRequest"

{"byPassCache":true,"flattenXML":false,"attributeFormat":"csv"} --Boundary_1_1153447573_1465550731355--

Used reference
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/bip/BIPAP/op-v1-reports-%7BreportPath%7D-run-post.html

Tried with encoded report path as well
https://example.oraclepdemos.com:432/xmlpserver/services/rest/v1/reports%2FCustom%2FISW%2FISW_OCA_Data_Access_Report/run?P_Sec_Attr=Hello&P_File_Identifier=11022323171717